# Oracle - Converting SDO_GEOMETRY to WKT?

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I am very new to oracle spatial.

I have a spatial table with one SDO_GEOMETRY column. After inserting POINT data in this table, I want to retrieve data in WKT format.

Here is what I did:

Inserting data -

```
INSERT INTO new_test (name, geom) VALUES (
'Test', 
SDO_GEOMETRY(
             2001,
             4326, 
             SDO_POINT_TYPE(12,14,NULL), 
             NULL, 
             NULL));
```

Fetching data -

```
SELECT NAME, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOM) AS point FROM NEW_TEST;
```

Output -

```
NAME | POINT
-------------
Test | (null)
```

Why do I get null here? Shouldn't it display the co-ordinate points?

Answer (score 10):

Too long for a comment - not sure why it doesn't work for you but I cannot replicate your results:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE new_test ( name varchar2(20), geom SDO_GEOMETRY );

INSERT INTO new_test (name, geom)
VALUES (
  'Test', 
  SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(12,14,NULL), NULL, NULL)
);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT NAME, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOM) AS point FROM NEW_TEST;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME POINT                                                                          
---- -----------------
Test POINT (12.0 14.0)
```

Comment: It's weird. I'm using oracle locator (The free version of oracle spatial). Also, database is setup in a linux box (fedora). Could any of this be the reason for such output (I highly doubt, but still?) 


As per [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_locator.htm#SPATL340) - SDO_UTIL is supported by oracle locator.

Comment: That function is definitely part of Locator. What tool are you using to show the results. Clearly not SQLPLUS ... Maybe that tool is just unable to show the result - the string returned is a CLOB.

Comment: Another possible is to use the get_wkt() method of the object type: SELECT NAME, t.GEOM.get_wkt() AS point FROM NEW_TEST t; Just don't forget to use an alias for the table (here "t").

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Yes yes! I am using sqldeveloper. Also, the get_wkt() query gave the same result (null). Am I missing any kind of configuration? I also tried executing query in windows 7 machine (VM). Got the same error.

Comment: Anyone who could assist me with this?

Comment: You say you get an error, but I don't see any error, just you get a NULL result. Did you try using sqlplus ? If you really get NULL results that means the geometry column itself contains NULLs. Are you sure your insert completed successfully ? Can you do a SELECT * FROM NEW_TEST ?

Comment: Not an  ERROR error per se. I meant in-appropriate output (my bad). Yes I tried sqlplus. It gave blank output in POINT column. And yes insert statement did execute successfully. 

Output for `SELECT * FROM NEW_TEST;` gives `NAME=Test` and `GEOM=MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY`.
Another query I tried - 

`SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POINT (12 14)')) AS DATA FROM DUAL;`.

Output : null

Answer (score 4):

The function `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY` seems not to be available in the **Express version** ([Source](https://community.oracle.com/thread/969716) - *Siva Ravada-Oracle*):

> Oracle Express does not have a Javavm in the database and the WKT
>   conversion routines need this as the feature is implemented as Java
>   stored procedures. So these WKT routines are not supported on the
>   Express edition.

You can still build your own WKT like this (for points):

```
SELECT name, 'POINT ('||t.X||' '||t.Y||')' AS point FROM NEW_TEST p, TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(p.GEOM)) t;
```