# How to read out geometric data from Oracle DB in MDSYS format and convert to shapely format or GeoJson?

Tags: python, pandas, gis, cx-oracle

I'm reading out an Oracle DB with geospatial geometries which I save in a pandas dataframe, say `df` having a geometric object of format `<cx_Oracle.Object MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY at 0x7f28` in a column named 'geometry'. Let's store it as:

```
g = df.geometry[0]
```

What I want to do:

Transform the data stored `g` to present it on a folium map as a PolyLine from shapely. I know that it consists of a bunch of points representing a line object.

What I can do:

1. I can read out the SDO_GTYPE, i.e. `g.SDO_GTYPE` gives `2002`.
2. I can read out SDO_ORDINATES, but it won't show me the coordinates, saying: `<cx_Oracle.Object MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY at 0x7f287848e4f0>`.

What I cannot do:

1. Transform geometric information with shapely and asShape:

```
from shapely.geometry import asShape
shape = asShape(g)
```

gives error: 'Context does not provide geo interface'.

2. Use Get_WKT() or any other functions in SQL-Statements

There are colleagues reading the data with a GIS-tool, i.e. why I doubt that the data is corrupt. I would be happy about any suggestions regarding this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have any experience with Oracle DB, but this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832223/oracle-converting-sdo-geometry-to-wkt) seems similar to yours.

Comment: This works fine for me. Seems like one should assign the geometry stored in SDO_GTYPE. Then it works.
`cur.execute('SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOMETRIE) AS line FROM CSVERSATEL.STWG1LRGG')
obj = cur.fetchone()`

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SpatialToGeoPandas.py) may be of help to you.